# Como calcular média de horário?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Tenho uma tabela nomeada `visitantes` nela eu insiro a `hora_que_entrou` e a `hora_que_saiu` do meu usuário em meu site.

Estas estão em formato `DATETIME`.

Gostaria de executar a média que eles passaram onlines, é possível isso sem recorrer a outra linguagem de programação?

Tentei algo como:

```
SELECT AVG(hora_que_entrou - hora_que_saiu) FROM `visitantes`
```

Mas não obtive êxito.

Comment: Você pode tentar fazer um casting das datas para time e tentar fazer a subtração.

Answer (score 4):

Presumindo que a composição da tabela esteja configurada corretamente seria assim usando a função [`TIMEDIFF`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff):

```
SELECT AVG(TIMEDIFF(hora_que_entrou, hora_que_saiu)) FROM `visitantes`
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Select/AverageTime.sql).

O resultado é dado em segundos.